# funtion insertAdjacentHTML not working in ie8

Tags: javascript

Works with chrome and firefox but not IE8

```
var SELECT = document.querySelector('.board select');
SELECT.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<option val="4000">4000</option>');
```

HTML

```
 <div class="board">
 <select></select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on older IE versions but there are some limitations on which html elements you can call this. If switching to jQuery is a option for you there are several way of doing this. Otherwise you might have to look into some polyfills for supporting older IE.

To make it work on IE8, in place of insertAdjacentHTML, you can use js code like

```
 var select = document.querySelector("select");
 var option = document.createElement('option');
 option.text = option.value = 4000;
 select.add(option, 0);
```

Comment: Surprising that [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) doesn't mention this caveat.